# How to bind to the control's dependency property inside ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I've extended `PopupBaseEdit` control by adding my own `ControlTemplate` and a new `DependencyProperty` `PopupText` to the extended control. The property `PopupText` is initialized from the control's consumer. No issues here. The question is; how do I bind `TextBox.Text` to my attached property inside `ControlContent`?

Here is the XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myPopuptemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Margin="5" Text="???????"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="local:myControl">
  <Setter Property="PopupContentTemplate" 
          Value="{StaticResource myPopuptemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`TemplateBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx).

Comment: when I am trying 'Text="{Binding Path={TemplateBinding PopupText}}"'  got _error MC3011: Cannot find the static member 'PopupTextProperty' on the type 'Control'_. However, such property exists

Comment: @user1153896: Have you even read the reference? TemplateBinding is **not** to be used in the path of a binding, it replaces a normal binding.

Comment: Text="{TemplateBinding PopupText}" - that gives the same compilation error. The attached property 'PopupText' is define

Comment: @user1153896: `TemplateBindings` are for normal DependencyProperties not attached properties, also: You neeed to set the `ControlTemplate.TargetType` to the type of your control, otherwise the compiler won't know which properties are there.

Comment: <ControlTemplate x:Key="myPopuptemplate" TargetType="local:myControl"> - gives runtime error {"'myControl' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'PopupContentControl'."}

Comment: @user1153896: You are setting the template as the `PopupContentTemplate` obviously the control it is going to be applied to is a `PopupContentControl`, that beind said, i kind of doubt that you will have access to the properties you mentioned...